# Problema com last-child

Tags: css

um problema creio que simples pra quem é conhecido na area, meu problema é o seguinte, tenho um div "pai" e dentro desse div tenho 6 li e dentro do div "pai" tem o div "box_padrao" e esse "box_padrao" exibe 3 por linhas ai tem um margin-right de 5px e para tirar e margin da ultima li uso o last-child, só que o problema vem ai, ele só tira a margin da "box_padrao 6", e eu preciso que tire da "box_padrao 3" também, como eu faria essa magica? muito obrigado pela atenção

```
<style type="text/css">
  .pai{
    width: 408px;
  }
  .pai ul li .box_padrao{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    width: 132px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #ccc;
  }
  .pai ul li:last-child .box_padrao{
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<div class="pai">
    <ul>
      <li><div class="box_padrao">1</div></li>
      <li><div class="box_padrao">2</div></li>
      <li><div class="box_padrao">3</div></li>
      <li><div class="box_padrao">4</div></li>
      <li><div class="box_padrao">5</div></li>
      <li><div class="box_padrao">6</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome da mágica é: `nth-child`

```
.pai ul li:nth-child(3n) .box_padrao{
  [...]
}
```

a cada 3 `li` ele irá aplicar essa propriedade. que no caso, na 3 e na 6

Comment: amigo e como eu faria pra tirar a margin-bottom da 4,5,6 sem afetar a margin-bottom: da 1,2,3 ?

Comment: `.pai ul li:nth-child(n+4) .box_padrao{
  margin-bottom: none;
}`

Comment: amigo desculpa minha insistencia, e como eu faria pra tirar a margin-top de 3 div sem afetar as demais div

Comment: consegui resolver, dei uma olhada nesse artigo http://blog.rafaelcavalcante.com/como-o-seletor-nth-child-funciona/ muito obrigado pela tua ajuda, me ajudo bastante e não consegui marcar 1 ponto na tua resposta, abraço